# Employed but no income tax receipts present right now... How to apply Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, proof-provenance-of-funds

I want to travel to Europe (Paris - Geneva) but I don't have income tax receipts of past 3 years for Schengen visa, since I have joined recently. Moreover I don't have 6 months pay slips. Please tell me are these mandatory documents for first time traveller? If yes then let me know what are the alternatives?

I have referred to the [following link](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/documents.html) for documents checklist.

Answer (score 4):

- If you worked for another company, use the tax receipts/payslips for that company
- else, just provide your current payslip and photocopy of your current bank statement. Explain your situation to the officer. From my own experience you can also ask your current company to provide a reference letter saying that you are currently working for the company and will be back to your own company to continue working at the company ( and will not stay in schengen area searching for job )